# How to get .m files to save properly from Sublime and work in Matlab editor

Tags: matlab, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime to write Matlab .m files and when I save the file, I can see these changes in the Matlab editor, however some of these changes will not be reflected when the code is running.  For example if I add a property `newprop` to a class `classname` in Sublime, save, open Matlab editor to see the changes, save again, then run `properties(classname)` in the command window, the new property is not shown among the list of properties.

Does anyone know how to edit a .m file in Sublime and make these changes work properly in Matlab without having to delete and retype in the Matlab editor?

Comment: first run `clear <yourclassname>`, see  [Automatic Updates for Modified Classes](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/modifying-and-reloading-classes.html)

Comment: As @rinkert says, you'll need to use `clear`. If you have an instance of the object in a variable in memory then you'll need to `clear` that too...